# Fauxton CouchDB doesn't show the data from blockfile

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger-fabric

I am using fabric 2.0 and CouchDB as a state database.

The data in the blockfile are correct (according the input I entered via the WebApp)
When I go to fauxton (http://localhost:6984/_utils/#database) I can't see the values (e.g. value1 : 4, value2: ID, ...)

I only receive this via fauxton:
Normally there should be also "_value1" :"4" ,...

```
{
  "_id": "\u0000key~timestamp\u0000co\u00002021-04-30T08:47:23.961Z\u0000",
  "_rev": "1-210ffdc0",
  "~version": "CgMBBgA=",
  "_attachments": {
    "valueBytes": {
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "revpos": 1,
      "digest": "md5-n7UoN6woal8ve/9S9DrNTA==",
      "length": 48,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
```

}

Does anyone has an idea, why the data in the blockfile are correct, but doesn't show up in the right way in fauxton?

I checked the docker-compose-couch.yaml and it's correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value cannot be parsed as JSON, it will be stored in CouchDB as a binary attachment. Fauxton UI only shows the digest of the binary value, not the actual binary attachment.

Comment: Thank you @Dave ! It works.... The values didn't parsed as JSON...